# Why do Django and gettext fail to load my 'zh' translations?

Tags: django, localization, internationalization, translation, gettext

Django's default `LANGUAGES` settings contains `zh-cn` and `zh-tw`.  However, I would like to use `zh` instead of `zh-tw`.  I've set up my `LANGUAGES` setting appropriately and compiled the gettext messages but Django will only load the `zh-cn` translation.

Frustratingly, gettext *will* load the `zh` translation fine if I delete the `zh_CN` directory!

Is there any way to get `zh` to load the right translation?

Answer (score 0):

My assumption on this is because django itself is only translated into zh-cn and zh-tw. Django translation will only allow you to translate into a language Django itself is translated for.

You should try to translate Django into zh (or copy zh-tw into zh).

Comment: Good idea, but unfortunately I've already tried copying `zh_TW` into `zh` and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the "Using Gettextize software" from GNU C help.

http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Using-gettextized-software.html

Quote:

> The file /usr/share/locale/locale.alias (replace /usr with whatever
>   prefix you used for configuring the C library) contains a mapping of
>   alternative names to more regular names. The system manager is free to
>   add new entries to fill her/his own needs. The selected locale from
>   the environment is compared with the entries in the first column of
>   this file ignoring the case. If they match the value of the second
>   column is used instead for the further handling.

Note that the in some system (e.g. Fedora 21), `/usr/system/locale/locale.alias` is obsoleted and just for backward compatibility.